# Create nodes unlimited times

Tags: nodes, forms, ajax

I've been trying to ajaxify the node creation form, the purpose?

- Save the node and remains in the node creation page (Done)
- If the user clicks the save button again save a new node

The second point is not working yet because once the Ajax request is sent again the previous created node is updated.

I tried with:

```php
function saveAjaxForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new AlertCommand('Saved'));

  return $response;
}
```

It works, but other #submit callbacks in the form aren't called again.

How can I "execute again" all the submit functions in the form?

Comment: Rather than Ajax why not use Drupal's destination=... query parameter to redirect back to the add node form?  This will start a fresh node generation form.

Comment: The idea is to keep the information to add a new node (maybe with small changes)

Comment: For some reason the Ajax response wasn't updating the form_build_id info, so I added a new Ajax Command: `$response->addCommand(new UpdateBuildIdCommand($old_form_build_id, $new_form_build_id));` it solves the issue

Comment: Great, do you mind posting this and the final code as answer? Especially where you get the form build IDs from, probably $form.

Answer (score 1):

For some weird reason the Ajax response wasn't updating the ***form_build_id*** value and the request takes it as the same form, so I added a new Ajax Command:

```php
function saveAjaxForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $old_form_build_id = $form['#build_id'];
  $new_form_build_id = $old_form_build_id.rand();

  $response = new AjaxResponse();

  $response->addCommand(new UpdateBuildIdCommand($old_form_build_id, $new_form_build_id));
  $response->addCommand(new AlertCommand('Saved'));

  return $response;
}
```

It solves the issue.